# How to to a top bar in objective c

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a class that is viewcontroller and I'v putted it inside of tabbar.
I want to have a top bar with text on it and I dont know how to do it, [like this](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/406/oldmain.png/).
Now I'm using a label and place it at the top but isnt the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your view controller inside a navigation controller or use [UINavigationBar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html) as a standalone object. Just create an instance of UINavigationBar and add it to view hierarchy like any other subview.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using interface builder to achieve this, a `UINavigationBar` can be added like this.

[image]

All you have to do is drag and drop.